# Navigation Bar Dash to Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a Flask application and have a page which would have the Dash application. The Flask application would have a the below pages

```
 Home (/)
 Login (/login)
 Logout (/logout)
 Dashboard (/dashboard)
```

Only the /dashboard is the Dash application which is redirected from the Login page post authentication. Everything works fine.

But I need to have Navigation bar from the /dashboard to go back to the Flask application Pages.

```
dbc.NavbarSimple(
        children=[
            dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Home", href="/")),
            dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Logout", href="/logout")),
            dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Dashboard", href="/dashboard")),
        ],
        brand="NavbarSimple",
        brand_href="#",
        color="primary",
        dark=True,
        )
```

I tried with the above code and I get the Navigation Bar. If I hover my mouse over the links I get the proper links like "http://127.0.0.1:5000/logout" and if i click on the link, the link on the URL in the browser is changing as well. But the page never loads and stuck on the same dashboard page.

Has anyone faced a similar issue? I'm using Chrome and tried on IE as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working by just making a simple change of setting external link as True. Adding my answer in case anyone else is stuck at the same issue I faced.

```
dbc.NavbarSimple(
        children=[
            dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Home", href="/", external_link=True)),
            dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Logout", href="/logout", external_link=True)),
            dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Dashboard", href="/dashboard", external_link=True)),
        ],
        brand="NavbarSimple",
        brand_href="#",
        color="primary",
        dark=True,
        )
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer to my question